# Getting stucked with number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to solve a php error, and Im getting stucked. The error I get is

PHP Warning:  number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in..

This is the full code

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($response->data["line_items"]); $i++){

        $variation_id = $response->data["line_items"][$i]["variation_id"];
        $product_id = $response->data["line_items"][$i]["product_id"];
        if($variation_id){
            $purchase_price = get_post_meta($variation_id, 'purchase_price', true);
        }else{
            $purchase_price = get_post_meta($product_id, 'purchase_price', true);
        }

        // if ($purchase_price)    om niet altijd mee te sturen.
        $response->data["line_items"][$i]["meta_data"][] = new WC_Meta_Data(array(
            "key"   => "purchase_price",
            "value" => (double)$purchase_price,
        ));

        $response->data["line_items"][$i]["meta_data"][] = new WC_Meta_Data(array(
            "key"   => "own_stock",
            "value" => (bool)get_field("product_delivery_own_stock", $product_id),
        ));


        $product_suppliers = get_field('product_supplier', $product_id);

        if(!empty($product_suppliers)){
            foreach($product_suppliers as $product_supplier){
                $supplier = $product_supplier->slug;

                $supplierCostPrice = number_format(str_replace(',', '.', $purchase_price), 2, '.', '') . " {$supplier}";

                $response->data["line_items"][$i]["meta_data"][] = new WC_Meta_Data(array(
                    "key"   => "cost_price_supplier",
                    "value" => (string)$supplierCostPrice,
                ));
            }
        }else{
            $supplier = 'no-supplier';

            $supplierCostPrice = number_format(str_replace(',', '.', $purchase_price), 2, '.', '') . " {$supplier}";

            $response->data["line_items"][$i]["meta_data"][] = new WC_Meta_Data(array(
                "key"   => "cost_price_supplier",
                "value" => (string)$supplierCostPrice,
            ));
        }

    }

    return $response;

});
```

The part throwing the error is

`$supplierCostPrice = number_format(str_replace(',', '.', $purchase_price), 2, '.', '') . " {$supplier}";`

The product price is always numeric, when set, unsure why I get this error. My guess is that the post_meta is stored as a string and I should convert the string somehow  which Im unsure how to, and also have a fix for if the price field is empty.

Comment: 1st likely problem: the str_replace will replace all the "," with ".". So if the data is 10,000, it will be 10.000 (I think fine), but if it is 10,000,000, then it will become 10.000.000 (two decimal points).  2nd likely problem : as you said, the product price may be empty, in that case please detects whether it is empty and if so, you may replace it with ZERO or do other actions

Comment: Thanks, I guess my thoughts are not to much off - unsure how to write it though.